# Is there a way to reduce load balancer cost with aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I use AWS for my businesses, and i have a load balancer for every website of mine, only in order to have HTTPS (because it is easy to setup).

Now the problem is that load balancers costs are related to the quantity of traffic that the website receive, and because i just make money out of the quantity of traffic, i do not get any profit for many months now, so:

-Is there a way to setup HTTPS on an EC2 instance website without having to pay for quantity of traffic ? is ssh commands the only option ? if not i would love to know how, if yes i would love to know how too :)

Thanks a lot for helping me out

Comment: using load balancers just to use https just doesn't worth the price. i suggest you buying a third party certificate or change your architecture to a serverless approach, so you can use `api gateway` which has https protocol for free.

Comment: Or you can [Get A Free SSL Certificate From AWS - Lawrence McDaniel](https://blog.lawrencemcdaniel.com/get-free-ssl-certificate-aws/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes but then the only way to be using this sweet "free certificate" from aws is by setting up a load balancer, which cost me 200$ a month since 6 months... So i basically paid around 1200$ just to have a FREE SSL certificate kindly delivered by aws so my website can be HTTPS.

Comment: Ah! True! It looks like the ACM certificate can only be used on a Load Balancer or a CloudFront distribution. In that case, you should buy a normal certificate elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can save money reducing the amount o ALB.
The usage (traffic) will be the same, so you will not save money on this, but you pay also for each ALB hours.

You can have just one ALB with many target groups (each one for each site).
On this one ALB you can have many certificate also.

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/

Comment: But will it need to change the different port for each site?

Comment: No, you can have listener condition based on host header.

Answer (score 0):

Have a single ALB that can serve up to 10 sites and redirect your HTTP traffic to HTTPS.
You can keep https on different port number

Comment: For a stronger answer, try including more detail and formatting your text in a more readable way. And also, Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @Eswanth.